# value avro is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro

I have am using cloudera 5.4.1 and spark 1.3.0

I wrote this code

```
val path = "/input/"
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("Form Submissions")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlConf = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlConf.read.avro(path)
df.foreach(println)
```

and this is my sbt file

```
name := "SparkAvro"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  //"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.5.2" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.5.2" % "provided",
  "com.databricks" % "spark-avro_2.10" % "1.0.0"
)

mainClass in assembly := Some("com.abhi.SparkAvro")
```

When I build this project it fails with this error message

```
[error] /Users/ab/MyProjects/SparkAvro/src/main/scala/com/abhi/SparkAvro.scala:17: 
value avro is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader
[error]     val df = sqlConf.read.avro(input)
[error]                           ^
[error] one error found
```

So it seems that the documentation on the github page for Spark Avro is for version 2.0.1 and those APIs don't apply to 1.0 version of Spark Avro.

I tried searching the web but I couldn't find the documenation which will show me how to write code on Spark Avro 1.0 and be able to parse Avro files on HDFS.

Comment: Did you add import com.databricks.spark.avro._ ?

Comment: here are my imports `import org.apache.spark._
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader`

Comment: Still the same issue `value avro is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader
[error]     val df = sqlConf.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").avro(path)`

Comment: I didn't say .avro, but .load :)

Comment: yes that worked. Sorry for not reading your answer. could you report as an answer so that I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace that line with:

```
sqlConf.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(path)
```

The reason is that, as you said, the code you copy/pasted from spark-avro's wiki is for the version 2.0.1. However, if you switch to the tag 1.0.0 (or the version you are using) on [github](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/tree/v1.0.0), it will show you all data related to that particular version - documentation included.

In that specific case, you will see a bunch of different ways to do the same as you did, but the reason behind that is that Spark API is also changing. Remember that Spark is moving really fast, so you will see a lot of examples online that are all using different methods - and you will often see that they are obsolete.

For example, in the documentation for the version 1.0.0, there is the call to .load(path,format). According to the [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext), it is deprecated since 1.4.0 - use `read.load(...)`.

Comment: I changed your line to be sqlConf.read.format..... because when I had read() I saw the error message "error: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader does not take parameters"

Comment: @StevenMagana-Zook thanks - I updated the answer. I cannot vertify now, so I trust your words :)

Answer (score 2):

Importing implicit conversion also works

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
```